# Multicolor LED based on different input voltages

Tags: led

Is it possible to have one LED produce different colors of light at different voltages.
Ex.
2v - Red
3v - Green
4v - Blue

I have looked at some other answers and searched on Google but it seems there might be a need to have comparator circuit. This is not the solution I am looking for.

So, if i buy a multi-color LED and hook it to a variable voltage adapter, can I get 3 different colors at 3 different voltages?

Comment: You could put 2 LEDs together with opposite polarities, so that a negative voltage would turn on one and a positive voltage would turn on another.

Comment: Multicolor LEDs that you can buy normally have more than 2 wires. They are actually just more than 1 LED combined into 1 package.

Comment: You're going to need some circuitry somewhere to make the colour decision. LEDs themselves are of fixed colour, but you can get multiple of them combined in a package.

Comment: @justin bi-color 2 pin leds exist. And you can get a 3rd color by alternating the pins quickly. Of course that needs active circuits.

Comment: There are "smart RGB leds" that can be controled with I2C.
Maybe it would be possible to make a circuit using only a low voltage microcontroller that could detect its own supply voltage and enables a different digital output for each voltage. Each output would be connected to a current limiting resistor, and the resistor for one of the leads of a RGB led.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that, but you wouldn't get to pick the colors or voltages.

For example, if you got an RGB LED (actually 3 LEDs in one package) and connected them all in parallel, the red one would be the first to illuminate at its rated forward voltage.  Second to illuminate would be the green, giving you a yellow or orange hue.  Finally, when you reached the forward voltage of the blue LED, you might see something approaching white.

Without additional circuitry, you don't have much control of the threshold voltages or colors other than part selection.